# How to replace the text between 2 characters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I want to remove the content between 2 characters in a text with Visual C#. 
Here is an example:

> Given: Hi [everybody], I'm 22 years old, I'm a student [at a University of Technology] in Vietnam 
>   Result: Hi, I'm 22 years old, I'm a student in Vietnam

I use this syntax

```
string input = "Hi [everybody], I'm 22 years old, I'm a student [at a University of Technology]";
string regex = "(\\[.*\\])";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
```

but the code is remove all between the first and the last square brackets, so this is the result:

> Hi in Vietnam

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, so your expression matches as many characters as possible between a `[` and a `]` - including many other `[`s and `]`s..

You can fix this one of two ways:

- Add a `?`. which makes the `*` *not* greedy: `.*?` will match as *few* characters as it can before matching the `]`.
- Replace the `.` with `[^]]`, which will only let the expression match non-`]` characters inbetween the `[` and the `]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace everything between `[...]` with empty string

```
\s+\[[^\]]*\]
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/7)

OR use `Non-greedy` way but read first [✽ Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#lazy_warning)

```
\s+\[(.*?)\]
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/8)

Comment: You're welcome. Follow the link, it's worth reading. First option is better than second.

Answer (score 0):

To match the text to replace use:

```
\s+\[.*?]
```

As C# String this is:

```
@"\s+\[.*?]"
```

If you use @ in front of the string you don't need to escape it in C#.

Comment: thank you, a small change can make program run perfectly